# LinkedIn API - Access Billing Transactions/Receipts from Ad Accounts

Tags: linkedin-api

We are trying to retrieve the billing receipts of all our Ad Accounts, through the LinkedIn API.

We can see the billing receipts in the "Billing Center" dashboard, however reading through the API there doesn't seem to be a way to access these receipts. Have we missed something? Or is there no way to access these receipts through the API?

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billing APIs don't exist. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/usecases/ad-tech/hierarchy

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.